# Are all ordinals higher than $ω$ epsilon numbers?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

By definition,  $α$ is an epsilon number iff $α=ω^α$. Indeed, the $ε$, $ζ$, and $η$ numbers are all epsilon numbers. But is $ω_1$ also an epsilon number? It seems that $ω^{ω_n}=ω_n$ for $n > 0$, which would mean that even ordinals $ω_1$ to $α↦ω_α$ are all epsilon numbers.

Edit: What I meant was ordinals greater than all the $ω_0$ numbers.

Edit 2: Yes, every initial ordinal greater than $ω$.

Thank you.

Comment: What does "greater than all the $\omega_0$ numbers" mean? What is an "$\omega_0$ number"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, as written the answer is obviously **no**: $\omega+1$ is an ordinal greater than $\omega$ which is not an $\epsilon$-number.

However, I suspect you meant to ask whether every *cardinal* greater than $\omega$ (or if you prefer, every *initial ordinal* greater than $\omega$) is an $\epsilon$-number. The answer to this, as you suspect, is **yes**. The key point is that as long as $\alpha$ is infinite we have $\vert\alpha\vert=\vert\omega^\alpha\vert$ (where *ordinal* exponentiation is being used here, of course). This means that any uncountable cardinal is a limit of $\epsilon$-numbers, and any limit of $\epsilon$-numbers is again an $\epsilon$-number.